# Remove short tag in html 4 validation using aspx

Tags: asp.net, html, html4

I am new to HTML 4 validations, in that if I put  HEAD runat="server" tag

I am getting this error - Error  Line 6, Column 82: character data is not allowed here

…lesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />

In the head tag I have called css files.

So if any one know about thin can help me,how to solve this error?
Thanks in advance. and sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use this --
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
then try this LINK <href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">

then you will get the solution.